# error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build my ionic 3 application and deploy and live reload on my device for that reason I am trying following command:

```
ionic cordova run ios --device --prod -lcs
```

But after running that command, I get below error:

```
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found
```

and

```
"No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
```

It says `To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.` but how in cordova?

Some additional error output. As you can see below, first `Archive Succeeded` but then it failed.

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

2018-03-21 15:34:28.042 xcodebuild[1673:18415] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging   _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/rh/w_gp1jjn4zz2mhhhnkq3_xqh0000gn/T/RemoteWorkersEvents_2018-03-21_15-34-28.034.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-03-21 15:34:31.900 xcodebuild[1673:18415] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fa985924610>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed.,    IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 \"No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found\"     UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found"    UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

(node:1256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,RemoteWorkersEvents.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios/build/device
(node:1256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Here is more output**

```
Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: email@email.com (7V8DET9FFF)"
*****------>>>>>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: io.ionic.dne" // <--- Here it says different profile which is correct because I set it up in xcode for this project.
                      (c37524bf-b317-4957-85a4-01877cfac047)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 0180A41A2E305542B7292E256F380F50BADCD73B --entitlements /Users/zafar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RemoteWorkersEvents-dxaeeftqppxbkmehuratdfbvdnom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RemoteWorkersEvents/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RemoteWorkersEvents.build/Debug-iphoneos/RemoteWorkersEvents.build/RemoteWorkersEvents.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/zafar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RemoteWorkersEvents-dxaeeftqppxbkmehuratdfbvdnom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RemoteWorkersEvents/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/RemoteWorkersEvents.app

Validate /Users/zafar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RemoteWorkersEvents-dxaeeftqppxbkmehuratdfbvdnom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RemoteWorkersEvents/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/RemoteWorkersEvents.app
    cd /Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/node_modules/.bin:/Users/zafar/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
    builtin-validationUtility /Users/zafar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RemoteWorkersEvents-dxaeeftqppxbkmehuratdfbvdnom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RemoteWorkersEvents/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/RemoteWorkersEvents.app

Touch build/device/RemoteWorkersEvents.app.dSYM
    cd /Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/node_modules/.bin:/Users/zafar/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios/build/device/RemoteWorkersEvents.app.dSYM

** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

2018-03-24 13:47:59.274 xcodebuild[3032:92302] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/rh/w_gp1jjn4zz2mhhhnkq3_xqh0000gn/T/RemoteWorkersEvents_2018-03-24_13-47-59.269.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-03-24 13:48:02.328 xcodebuild[3032:92302] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fb937015e10>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 \"No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}"
)}
*****------>>>>>    error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found // <--- Here it says different profile which is default but I changed it the one above

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

(node:2553) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,RemoteWorkersEvents.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/zafar/Documents/Projects/dne/ne-frontend/platforms/ios/build/device
(node:2553) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2553) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please check the line begins with `*****------>>>>>` Those are the two lines I am concerned with and I think something weird is happening there. Any idea what is happening here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

To deploy and test an app on an iOS device you need to create a developer certificate and a provisioning profile.

> iOS developers need to generate a provisioning profile to code sign
> their apps for testing. The good news is that, as of iOS 9, you can
> develop and test your apps on your iOS device without a paid Apple
> Developer account. This is particularly great for developers who want
> to try out mobile development with Ionic since it saves the cost but
> still provides a lot of the features of having a full Apple Developer
> account. For a full breakdown of the features included, check out
> [Apple’s docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1).

**Basic Requirements to run your iOS app:**

- MacOS (10.10 or higher)
- Xcode 7 or higher
- iOS 9
- A free Apple ID or paid Apple Developer    account

**Need to Generate Certificate & Profile:**

Open your Xcode > Go to Preferences > Account > Add account

[image: Xcode screenshot preferences accounts]

Add Your Apple account credential:

[image: Xcode screenshot sign in]

[image: Xcode screenshot project settings]

**Now Come back to the ionic project and follow below steps:**

- Run a build (production or debug) of your app with below command

  $ionic cordova build ios --prod
- Open the `.xcworkspace` file from path `platforms/ios/` in Xcode.

**For Profile Selection from XCode follow below steps:**

Now Go to your App Setting (By clicking on App name in Left Menu panel)

[image]

Check "Automatically manage signin" (by checking this Xcode will create a profile automatically)

After setting all this now your app is ready to test on the device there are 2 ways to run your app on the device.

1. Directly run your app from XCode by hitting on the play button on the top left corner.
2. run `$ionic cordova run ios --device` through your ionic project terminal.

Hope above steps will help to run your app on the iOS device.

Useful links :

1. [How to deploy app on device (android & iOS)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)
2. [Apple Certificate Sign in flow](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7)

Comment: What happens is that when I build using `ionic cordova build ios --prod` command and then open the project in xcode to change the Bundle ID. After changing that I run `ionic cordova run ios --device` or `ionic cordova run ios --device --prod -lcs` then I still get same error. No difference even the bundle ID is changed in xcode but with command it show not profile for `io.ionic.starter`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before and I fixed it by actually archive and validate the ios app using xcode GUI. That creates the provisioning profile you need if you check the "automatic managing signing". (P.s. If that fails to validate, then it is because of some other reason which you need to google) After all the necessary provisioning profiles are automatically created by xcode. Then, try run the command again. It should work this time! I hope that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

just add quotes between the name bundle identifier!

ex:

"io.ionic.starter"

or

-io.ionic.starter-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it writing my email but instead of the "@"I wrote a quote "-". That gave me the certificate and now it is working.