# An App ID with Identifier 'com.app.appname' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I'm getting this error when I try to register a new Bundle ID:

"*An App ID with Identifier 'com.app.myappname' is not available. Please enter a different string.*"

I'm using Ionic/Cordova so I haven't been using much Xcode.

I've seen other stackoverflow pages with the same questions but they all relate to Xcode 7.3.

I'm currently using Xcode 9.2. I didn't know if there was a more recent fix for this -  as most of the resources are 2 years outdated

Comment: Make sure in your app config.xml file in the main app folder, you have set up the widget id with the same App ID as you used on the Developer Portal:

<widget id="com.<yourcompany>.<yourappname>" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide your Unique bundle ID which is used for your app-building and distribute on the app store.

As above "**com.app.myappname**" is a sample App Id you need to replace with yours like =>

```
com.yahoo.mailapp
```

Now next question is how to set your **App ID**?

You can set it through your ionic project from **Visual Studio Code** or from **XCode** itself.

**Set App Id from the ionic project (**Visual Studio code** or any other dev tool):**

1. Open Your Config.xml file and set :

   [image]

After doing this build your app and open it in your `XCode` and you will get your updated App Id in your `XCode`.

2. Now generate codesign for provided App Id.

Link -> [How to generate code sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413956/error-exportarchive-no-profiles-for-io-ionic-starter-were-found/49423104#49423104)

**Set App Id through Xcode:**

1. After building your app open your iOS generate code in Xcode.
2. Select Project -> General Tab -> Change your app Bundle Identifier

[image]

Hope this will help you to build your app.

Comment: Awesome tutorial!! However I'm still getting an error even after following all your steps. Both the ID's in the code and in xcode match.  I've already launched on Android so I'd hate to change my bundle ID. @CodeChanger

Comment: Which bundle id you have set for your android app ?

Comment: I fixed it - I happen to have another name I didn't know about that was tied to the bundle ID. Had to call apple to fix it!