# Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args deploying ionic app to IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I can’t deploy my Ionic App to iOS devices even after performing all of the tasks mentioned in this forum. I followed all of the steps required for code signing so I’m no longer getting that error. Now I’m getting the following:

**The following build commands failed:**

> Ld
>   /Users/laroca/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-bfqgfiilftgpjvcfjxixwpxvluxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/apname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appname
>   normal arm64 (1 failure) Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild
>   with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/laroca/Documents/Mundo/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,appname.xcworkspace,-scheme,Mundo,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,appname.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/laroca/Documents/appname/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/laroca/Documents/appname/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

**I tried the following to no avail:**

```
ionic remove platform ios
ionic platforms rm ios
ionic platforms add ios
ionic run
```

The code signing issue appears to be resolved but I can’t get past this current issue. Please help. I’ve never been able to deploy to IOS.

Answer (score -1):

For build or run iOS app you need to use below command :

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

or for release version

```
ionic cordova build ios --release
```

or for Prod build

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod -- release
```

and for code sign reference please check below answer link :

1. [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413956/error-exportarchive-no-profiles-for-io-ionic-starter-were-found/49423104#49423104)
2. [Ionic Official Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)

Hope this will helps!

Comment: ionic cordova build ios fails also:

Comment: ** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
 Ld build/emulator/Mundo.app/Mundo normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/laroca/Documents/Mundo/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Mundo.xcworkspace,-scheme,Mundo,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/laroca/Documents/Mundo/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/laroca/Documents/Mundo/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch